# SAS, to combine value of Column with Enter Key

Tags: sas

I want to combine some columns in SAS. Result of That will separated by Enter.

Like

[image: input]

The Result must be in column D. my Expecting Result is:

[image: output]

I need your help on how to provide column A B C to Be D like I showed above.

Many thanks,

Comment: So instead of data as output you want a REPORT?  What type of file do you want the report written to?  Excel file? PDF file? HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store a key into a variable.  You can store character strings. So what character(s) do you want to use?  Do you want to add linefeed? ('0A'x) or Carriage Return? ('0D'x) or perhaps both? ('0D0A'x)  Or some other character like '|' that you could specify as the SPLIT character so the values will actually display on multiple lines?

```
data want;
  set have ;
  length D $50 ;
  d = catx('0A'x,a,b,c);
run;
```